# How to resolve "Failed to Authenticate with service" error in AWS Elastic Disaster Recovery service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, disaster-recovery

I am trying to perform a cross region failover for EC2 instance in AWS using the AWS Elastic Disaster Recovery service. I am facing an issue while initiating the replicating agent at DR region at the point of Authenticate with service. However, this issue is not coming if i am allowing my data flow through public network. I am unable to understand the cause of the issue.

Also, can anyone tell me what does the option of "create public IP" mean when we select the option of "Use Private IP"?

Thanks